# How to return image using a /get route on Spark Java so it displays on the webpage?

Tags: java, mysql

As the title says, I am trying to display an image on a webpage using Spark Java. The image I am trying to retrieve was stored as a MEDIUMBLOB using mysql.

```
    File file = new File("image.jpg");
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedImage bi = null;
        System.out.println("Writing to File: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        try {


            String sql = "SELECT Image FROM images WHERE Image_ID = 0;";
            PreparedStatement statement = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            //writes image to file to make sure it the image come out right
            while(rs.next()){
                InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("Image");
                bi = ImageIO.read(input);
                int available = input.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[available];
                while(input.read(buffer) > 0){
                    output.write(buffer);
                }
            }



            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }



    return bi;
```

I am using a HTML form to call the function:

```
    <div class="get_file">
        <form method="get" action="/mainpage">
            <input type = "submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

When I run the program, instead of displaying the image it just gives me this text:

> BufferedImage@4b72a5d2: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 >color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@68f38796 transparency = 1 has alpha >= false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 274 height = 184 >#numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2

Comment: It seems you are using third party libraries. Please state which and tag your question correctly. Try to create a [mcve], emphasis on **complete**.

Comment: @Zabuza is this any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value is in fact a BufferedImage, you should be returning a byte array instead. I would suggest using a ByteArrayOutputStream for this purpose.

```
    byte[] rawImage = null;
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ImageIO.write( bi, "jpg", baos );

        baos.flush();
        rawImage = baos.toByteArray();
    }

    return rawImage;
```

---- EDITED ----

Make sure you include the "Content-Type" header in your response by specifying "image/jpeg"

Comment: Is it possible to do this for multiple images? I tried using an arraylist, but that didn't work

Comment: I am pretty sure you could, but I am missing lots of the puzzle pieces to be able to answer.